# Solaris 10 3/11 download page shows md5 number of iso image but I don't understand the few extra digits written beside md5 number

Tags: iso-image, solaris, md5

I've downloaded an iso image of x86 solaris 10 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/solaris/solaris10/downloads/solaris10-get-jsp-downloads.html) but I can't understand the md5 sum given in the download page because beside the main md5 number, there are another number.

Here is the digest.
(aae1452bb3d56baa3dcb8866ce7e4a08 **2254110720**: sol-10-u11-ga-x86-dvd.iso).

I got the number **aae1452bb3d56baa3dcb8866ce7e4a08** when I ran `$ md5sum sol-10-u11-ga-x86-dvd.iso` but I didn't get this number, **2254110720**.
I also checked with digests like sha256, sha1 or b2sum. Only md5sum gives the identical string without the second one.

Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is the file size in bytes. Possibly generated by a [specific tool or added by a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782702/md5-checksum-with-file-size).

It is useful to make sure your file is not truncated or incomplete.

2254110720 would be 2,254,110,720 bytes. Approximately 2.1GiB.

Comment: Mokubai_Thank you very much. One thing I can't understand that why file size is required here as md5 hashing ensures that a file is unaltered. I mean that's what these hashing are used for or I don't know how digest functions work. Thank again.

Comment: One possible reason I can think of would be Hash collisions. MD5 hashes are not unique and someone could potentially craft a (small) executable that has the same hash but a different size. While a file of the same size might be able to be crafted in a similar fashion it would likely be more difficult due to the quantity of data and algorithm. It also tells you that you have the right file.

Comment: Mokubai_I was unaware of this fact. I thought it was foolproof kind a system. Yes, that might be a reason. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Bishnu A bit late here, but no hash algorithm can ever be collision-free.  Hashes reduce all possible combinations of data of all possible lengths to a fixed size.  There is literally an infinite set of possible inputs to hash functions, but only a finite set of possible result hashes.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle  Hashes work because they're one-way calculations that are very difficult to reverse, so taking a hash and creating data to match that hash is hard. But as computers get more capable, that becomes more possible: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security

Comment: @AndrewHenle,  Not a bit but a byte/word late here. Thank you. I got it. :)